# "Currency is not a well-formed currency code" error message

Tags: trailhead

For a couple of days now, whenever I create an object record in a Trailhead Playground, after hitting "save" I land on the record details page with an error and cannot see any fields:

[image]

I already logged a case with Trailhead Support. Posting this just in case any of you are also stuck with this.

Comment: Please note the format here is question and answer as separate types of post. This information would be better to share as a clearly distinguished question, and then a clearly distinguished answer to it. As written, there is nothing to answer here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for pointing that out. I just edited the post based on your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not find any information on such error so I figured I'd go to [Setup > Company Information] and noticed the *Currency Locale* was set to "Spanish - null". I changed it to "English (Unided States) - USD" —I guess any not null value would do— and **this fixed it for me**.